# Methods you cannot implicitly call in a copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I was wondering if anyone could explain this question to me:

> Given
>
> ```
> class Fruit {...};
> class Orange : public Fruit {....};
> ```
>
> Which of the following methods are NEVER implicitly called at position
>   XXX in the following code?
>
> ```
> Orange::Orange(const Colour &colour) XXX {...}
> ```
>
> **A.** `Orange::Orange()`
>
> **B.** Default constructors for data member within class Orange
>
> **C.** `Fruit::Fruit()`
>
> **D.** Default constructors for data member within class fruit
>
> **E.** **A** and **C**
>
> **F.** **A** and **D**

The provided answer is **F**.

I was thinking that this is a copy constructor, and that class `Orange` is a child class and `Fruit` is a base class.

I wasn't sure why the answer would be **A**, and was thinking that the reason it is **D** is because `Orange` may have data members that `Fruit` doesn't have, therefore you cannot use it's default constructor.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Not a very good question. The default constructors for `Fruit` members *are* called, not just at position XXX but as a result of calling `Fruit::Fruit()`.

Comment: @BoPersson it's just a question given from my lecturer I'm struggling to get my head round it

Comment: @Lucy - I guessed that from the picture, but it is still a bit contrived.

Comment: Well I, for one, disagree. Everything that `Fruit`'s constructor calls transitively is implicitly called at the very beginning of the member initialization list, right in that `XXX`, default constructors for `Fruit`'s members included.

Comment: I think question implicitly excludes transitivity.

Comment: @Quentin - It's as matter of definition and that is why the question isn't a good one. At XXX the base class' default constructor is called, and it in turn initializes the `Fruit` members. Does that *really* happen at XXX, or in class Fruit?!

Comment: @BoPersson both, because the initialization of an `Orange` strictly contains the initialization of its `Fruit`. If you look at that line with the `XXX` and explicitly ask where the construction of `Fruit`'s members takes place, then the answer is obviously "inside the `XXX`". Making **D** a possible choice only to later disregard transitive calls is plain misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was thinking that this is a copy constructor ...

It is not. A copy constructor takes an instance of the same class, this constructor of Orange takes an instance of Colour as an argument

> ... and that orange class is a child class and fruit is a base class..

This is correct.

> I wasn't sure why the answer would be A ...

It is A because a constructor of Orange never implicitly calls another constructor of Orange.

> ... and was thinking that the reason it is D is because orange may have data members that fruit doesn't have therefore you cannot use it's default constructor.

I find this reasoning odd. I don't see how the members of Orange could affect how the members of Fruit can be constructed.

The wording of the question is ambiguous. The constructors of the members of Fruit are called within the constructor of Fruit, and since the constructor of Fruit is at the marked position, so are the constructions of its members - at least indirectly. So, whether D is an answer in addition to A depends on a technicality and how you interpret the question.

Comment: The question says: "are NEVER implicitly called", so cases where they could be called or not are not correct answers. This makes it (almost) clear in my opinion. Everything that could be called can be rules out as an answer.

Comment: @KarstenKoop Fair enough, my post scriptum was a bit pointless.